# Manipulation replacements rules from Solve

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, replacement

Assume the call to the routine `Solve[eqn==0,{x1,x2}]` returns:

```
{{x1->a1,x2->a2},{x1->b1,x2->b2}}
```

I would like to from the solutions matrix

```
{{a1,a2},{b1,b2}}
```

with a nice way.

Comment: See [this documentation article](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseRuleSolutions.html). (In your case, you could use `{x1,x2} /. solution`)

Comment: Consider also `{{x1->a1,x2->a2},{x1->b1,x2->b2}}/.Rule[_,val_]->val`

Comment: Or `Values /@ solution`.

Comment: .. or just `Values@solution`

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to get the right-hand-sides of a (arbitrarily nested) list of  `Rule`s is to use [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html):

```
rules = {a -> 1, {b -> 2, {c -> 3, a -> 4}}};
Values @ rules
```

> {1, {2, {3, 4}}}

For the list of rules returned by `Solve`:

```
solution = {{x1 -> a1, x2 -> a2}, {x1 -> b1, x2 -> b2}};
Values @ solution
```

> {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}

```
solution2 = Solve[y - x == a && x - y^2 == b, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 1/2 (1 - 2 a - Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b]),  y -> 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b])},
>   {x ->  1/2 (1 - 2 a + Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b]), 
>     y -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b])}}

```
Values @ solution2
```

> {{1/2 (1 - 2 a - Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b]),  1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b])},
>   {1/ 2 (1 - 2 a + Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b]),  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b])}}

Alternatively, define a function that returns the solution values directly (similar to [`DSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html)):

```
ClearAll[solveValue]
solveValue = Values @* Solve;

solveValue[y - x == a && x - y^2 == b, {x, y}]
```

> > {{1/2 (1 - 2 a - Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b]),  1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b])},
> >     {1/ 2 (1 - 2 a + Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b]),  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 a - 4 b])}}

Answer (score 1):

Check also the following. Let

```
sol = {{x1 -> a1, x2 -> a2}, {x1 -> b1, x2 -> b2}}
```

be your solution. Then try this:

```
sol /. {x_ -> a_, y_ -> b_} -> {a, b}

(* {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}  *)
```

Have fun!